# awk return another line when a specific line is equal to something

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to get the UUID of one of my HW USB license key.
Only way I found to get the UUID is to use the virtualbox command "VBoxManage list usbhost".

This command returns the following output:

```
UUID:               e41fb948-83af-40a8-85a0-b0fcd7afd13f
VendorId:           0x0529 (0529)
ProductId:          0x0001 (0001)
Revision:           2.22 (0222)
Port:               3
USB version/speed:  2/1
Manufacturer:       AKS
Product:            HASP HL 2.16
Address:            sysfs:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4//device:/dev/vboxusb/001/004
Current State:      Available

UUID:               7d8a98ab-e20c-4111-a873-6ce519729ed8
VendorId:           0x0529 (0529)
ProductId:          0x0001 (0001)
Revision:           3.37 (0337)
Port:               2
USB version/speed:  2/1
Manufacturer:       AKS
Product:            HASP HL 3.25
Address:            sysfs:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3//device:/dev/vboxusb/001/003
Current State:      Captured
```

What I'd like to do is make a bash function that takes a parameter which represent the Product: string (HASP HL 3.25 etc...) and returns the UUID on the first line.

I can get the output of the command from the script but then I'm a bit at a loss how to use awk to get back the UUID when product corresponds to a string.

```
UUIDS=`sudo -u syderal VBoxManage list usbhost | awk '/$1/ { print $2 }'`
```

I can use awk to find the Product: or UUID: line quite easily but how can I do it so that when Product: line is equal to a string it returns the UUID line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
sudo -u syderal VBoxManage list usbhost |
 awk -v product="HASP HL 3.25" '/^UUID:/ {uuid=$2}
                                /^Product:/ && $0 ~ product {print uuid}'
```

This gets the product value as a variable `product` (see we need `-v` to pass a shell value into `awk` as a variable). Then, it stores the UUID in the variable `uuid`, so that it can be used later on. It keeps changing whenever `UUID:` is found, so that in a given paragraph you always have the correct value. Finally, when `Product:` text is found and the line contains the given `product` variable.

#### Test

If I store your output in a file `a`:

```
$ awk -v product="HASP HL 3.25" '/^UUID:/ {uuid=$2} /^Product:/ && $0 ~ product {print uuid}' a
7d8a98ab-e20c-4111-a873-6ce519729ed8
```